# Transform table from start/end records to timeseries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that is organized as the first table below, and I would like to transform it into a table like the second, in a relatively efficient way. Thanks !

**Input**:

| id | start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2021 | 01-02-2021 | 3 |
| B | 01-04-2021 | 01-06-2021 | 4 |
| A | 01-04-2021 | 01-05-2021 | 5 |
| C | 01-02-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 6 |

**Target**:

| id | 01-01-2021 | 01-02-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 01-04-2021 | 01-05-2021 | 01-06-2021 | 01-07-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 6 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt`+`pivot`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'value'], value_name='col')
   .pivot_table(index='id', columns='col', values='value', fill_value=0)
   .reset_index() # optional
)
```

output:

```
id    01-01-2021   01-02-2021   01-03-2021   01-04-2021   01-05-2021   01-06-2021 
A              3            3            0            5            5            0
B              0            0            0            4            0            4
C              0            6            6            0            0            0
```